# How to use trial and error algorithm to predict the next number in a sequence?

Tags: python, markov-process, reinforcement-learning

I have a time series data. I want to use trial and error algorithms to predict the next number in a variation_sequence. I mean about Trial and error algorithm is using an online learning and where I do not have any more information on the sequence. There is a possibility to use order-n Markov predictor.

But I don't know which algorithm is suitable to order-n Markov predictor? If there is alternative possibility?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
year = [1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010]
variation_sequence = [449.48, 553.57, 696.783, 870.133, 1000.4, 1309.1]
plt.plot(year, variation, color='orange')
plt.xlabel('Variation')
plt.ylabel('year')
plt.title('Variation of data')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I want tol use an online learning.

Comment: @nbro yes exactly. I said trial and error beacause I think that is more general

Comment: @nbro I want to use two model linear regression and RL. Linear regression to fit data and RL to test the next step value. but I don't an example about how to do that. For that I am asking